# Developing MHEG application

Tags: simulator

I have downloaded OpenMHeg simulator..how to develop an application in mheg?what eclipse version i need to use?where do i get the sdk for mheg?

Comment: **-_-** Sorry, but no idea. **-_-**

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried yet. but I think it's worth trying. Someone said that the BBC's implementation of [MHEG5 is open sourced](http://purplefloyd.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/bbc-open-sources-mheg-toolkit/)

It can be downloaded from [mhegplus on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mhegplus/)

Comment: Note that MHEGPlus is not MHEG-5, but a preprocessor language that compiles to MHEG-5.

Answer (score 0):

There is no MHEG-5 SDK. There is some limited documentation available online, and a few discussions of the type hierarchy.

Since MHEG-5 has no support for user defined types and the API is completely provided by the implementation (in various states of brokenness), you only need an editor and an understanding of the application model to write applications.

I wrote an introduction to MHEGPlus a while ago but didn't go into any advanced application building techniques. There are a few more examples out there if you look for them.